# Is YHWH of Israel the counterpart of Pharoah of Egypt in Exodus 5:1?

Tags: exodus

Moses was leading the people of YHWH out of Egypt in the period of Egyptian history when her government was [theocratic](http://www.eternalegypt.org/EternalEgyptWebsiteWeb/HomeServlet?ee_website_action_key=action.display.topic.details&language_id=1&trait_item_id=10000212).

Israel was a theocratic nation and has no human king until Saul was anointed as the king of Israel.

> "And YHWH said to Samuel, “Listen to the voice of the people in all that they say to you, for it is not you they have rejected, but they have rejected Me as their king. " 1 Samuuel 8:7

Is YHWH of Israel the counterpart of Pharoah of Egypt in Exodus 5:1?  If yes, is YHWH a theocratic title like Pharoah is a theocratic title?

> Afterward, Moses and Aaron went to Pharaoh and said, “This is what YHWH, the God of Israel, says: ‘Let My people go, so that they may hold a feast to Me in the wilderness.’”

Comment: God speaks with Samuel regarding the matter of Israel wanting a king so that they could be like other nations. I think your question would have been better to be associated with God's own words to Samuel. ( I did not down-vote either question or answer myself. I am just making the suggestion.)

Comment: @NigelJ  Thanks!  I am going to edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The Divine Name in Hebrew is called the tetragrammaton and consists of four consonants: YHWH.  Because there are no vowels, the pronunciation is unknown although the closest may be Yahweh.  This is not a title but is the Divine Name.

The name Yahweh refers to God’s self-existence. Yahweh is linked to how God described Himself in Exodus 3:14, “God said to Moses, ‘I AM WHO I AM. This is what you are to say to the Israelites: “I AM has sent me to you.”’” God’s name is a reflection of His being. God is the only self-existent or self-sufficient Being. Only God has life in and of Himself. That is the essential meaning of the tetragrammaton, YHWH.

I am unable to understand how Egyptian dynasties could be described as "theocratic" given the Pharaohs were mere mortals who ruthlessly served their own ambitions and went to great lengths to cling to power.  A theocracy is where God is in control.

Forgive me if I have misunderstood your question, but I fail to make the connection between a Pharaoh of Egypt being looked upon as a god and YHWH who clearly demonstrated that ALL the gods and goddesses of Egypt were impotent.  YHWH has no counterparts.

Comment: The meaning of YHWH is the coupling of one Hebrew Verb twice "Hayah" =  "I shall/will be" See Ex 3:12.  The name is not as First Person Singular Pronoun; "I Am" that does not fit the Hebrew Grammar etc.right.   The Hebrew for "I Am " is "Ani".  See Deut 32:39 as one example.

Comment: @ethos - Are you suggesting that the tetragrammaton is a title, and not the Divine Name?

Comment: Oops, I mean the 'tetragram' = YHWH.  Jewish people refer to it as "The Name."

Comment: The meaning of the name which Jehovah (JHVH/YHWH) explained in Ex 3:14.  It is not just as statement of existence there is much more to it in Hebrew!    A Verb is a doing word as you know, so God by his name is stating he is going to acts for His people.

Answer (score 0):

NO.  As Pharoah considered himself God and in Egypt they, the people of Egypt, thought he was a God:-

> "Egyptian pharaohs were kings of Ancient Egypt, and **were considered gods by their culture**. Their titles equated them with aspects of the likes of the hawk god Horus, the vulture goddess Nekhbet, and the cobra-goddess Wadjet."-Goggle

So the false God King of Egypt was an oponent of "Jehovah" (JHVH) which was shown in the last plauge as it killed what the Egyptians thought was The Son Of God, Pharoah's firstborn child and the God king of Egypt, Pharoah was totaly powerless to stop it:-

> NWT Exodus 12:12  "For I will pass through the land of Egypt on this night and strike every firstborn in the land of Egypt, from man to beast; and ***I will execute judgment on all the gods of Egypt***. I am Jehovah.

This 10th plauge showed up Pharoah to be a hopeless powerless god as Jehovah, The Almighy God, showed that all thier gods were powerless against him during the 10 plauges.  Finaly Jehovah put the false God Pharoah to death at Red Sea crossing!  In Egypt during the time of Moses freeing the children of Israel from Egypt, it was a war between Gods, the Gods of the Egyptians and the one God of Moses, Jehovah, as to who was The True and Almighty God!

Futher to the above we could add the The Pharoah was the representative of God of earth as he was also considerd to be ***the son of the Sun God RA***:-

> "Ra-Horakhty-Atum was associated with Osiris as the manifestation of the sun at night. When Osiris was murdered by his brother Set, he became the God of the Underworld. Thus the Pharaoh was the son of Ra who ruled as the living Horus and who became Osiris on his death."-Goggle

So this will make him Gods spokesman on earth this would line him up against  Moses as the spokesman of The God of the Hebrews, Jehovah:-

> NWT Exodus 7:1, 2 "***J**ehovah then said to Moses***: “See, I have made you like God to Pharʹaoh**, and Aaron your own brother will become your prophet. 2 **You are to repeat everything that I will command you**, and Aaron your brother will speak to Pharʹaoh, and he will send the Israelites away from his land."

The "counterpart" to Pharoah was Moses as he spoke for Almighty God and Pharoah spoke for the God(s) of Egypt!!

As further parallel would be that Moses stands for Jesus (son of God) and his God Jehovah and Pharoah stands for the Son of RA (son of God) and his God Satan!

Note ref. the above:-

> Ra (Re) was the primary name of the sun god of Ancient Egypt. He was often considered to be the King of the Gods and thus the patron of the pharaoh and one of the central gods of the Egyptian pantheon. He was also described as the creator of everything. Ra was so powerful and popular and his worship was so enduring that some modern commentators have argued that the Egyptian religion was in fact a form of veiled monotheism with Ra as the one god. This seems to be somewhat of an overstatement, but underlines his primary position within religious texts throughout Egyptian history."-https://www.ancientegyptonline.co.uk/ra.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  Moses did not represent himself to see Pharaoh.  He was sent to see Pharaoh.  He was sent by YHWH.  YHWH was the counterpart of Pharaoh because they two, not Moses a servant of YHWH, were the top rulers of their own people.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, YHWH is the counterpart of Pharoah of Egypt in Exodus 5:1.

Then, is YHWH a theocratic title like Pharoah is a theocratic title?

YHWH was the God of Israelites in the sense that they worship Him and YHWH accept their worship. Exodus 5:3 And YHWH was also their king in the sense that they consider YHWH as their highest governmental ruler and YHWH consider them His people. Exodus 5:1; 1 Samuel 8:7

Pharaoh was the theocratic title of the king-god of Egypt who became a god when he or she become the king of Egypt by receiving the soul that could make the king divine. [Topics: Theocracy](http://www.eternalegypt.org/EternalEgyptWebsiteWeb/HomeServlet?ee_website_action_key=action.display.topic.details&language_id=1&trait_item_id=10000212)

So the transaction between YHWH and Pharaoh through Moses and Aaron was between two god-kings.

Therefore, yes, YHWH is a theocratic title as Pharaoh was a theocratic title.

Comment: Zero evidence to support this claim. The Bible tells us that YHWH is the eternal, uncreated creator of time, space, matter and life.  Pharaohs were merely created mortals. YHWH taught Pharaoh a severe lesson about sovereignty. YHWH is the One and the Only God. YHWH is NOT "a theocratic title" and there is zero comparison between YHWH and upstart dictators who claim divinity.

Comment: @Lesley  Thank you for your comment!  Is YHWH is a title or a personal proper name?

Comment: The tetragrammaton, YHWH, is not a title but is God’s name.

Comment: Most English Bibles translate YHWH into LORD - and LORD is a title.  But the tetragrammaton is the Divine Name of God.

Comment: @Lesley  Thank you for your comments!  How do you come to the conclusion that it is a name and not title?

Comment: @ Chin-Lee Chan – This Jewish article explains why Jews view YHWH as “The Name” and not as a title: http://www.jewfaq.org/name.htm   It says “The most important of God's Names is the four-letter Name represented by the Hebrew letters Yod-Hei-Vav-Hei (YHVH).”  Please also read:  https://www.britannica.com/topic/Yahweh and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God_in_Judaism

Comment: @Lesley  Thank you for the references!  So you come to the conclusion that YHWH is not possible to be a title because of these three articles.  Correct ?

Comment: @Lesley  I have scanned the first article and found two information.  Jews found that their God has many names, not just YHWH.  The site seem to have not discuss about any title at all in the site.  http://www.jewfaq.org/search.shtml?Keywords=title

Comment: these three articles are merely the tip of a huge iceberg, theologically speaking. I came to the conclusion that YHWH is the Divine Name (and not merely a title, such as LORD or GOD) more than 22 years ago after I became a Christian. It is the Bible that tells me God's Divine Name is the unpronouncable YHWH. And yes, God has more than one name,but YHWH is THE Name. Yours is an interesting question, but for the life of me, I can't see how YHWH is merely a title. Perhaps you could provide a link on that?

Comment: @Lesley  I see.  I have been a Christian about 37 years.  I only recently start doubting that YHWH is a personal name.  Why it takes so long?  Because I have not met a person or read anything about that YHWH may be a title until recently.  I will provide a link for your consideration soon.  Sorry that I have read https://www.britannica.com/topic/Yahweh and it does not find it discuss about that it cannot be a title.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86264/discussion-between-lesley-and-chin-lee-chan).

Comment: @Lesley Let's discuss in chat after this comment so that more people can see this comment. Sorry that the 3rd article did not discuss about why YHWH cannot be a title either https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God_in_Judaism.  The article suggested, that YHWH could be a title, could be wrong that only the fourth commandment contains the title and the name of the Lawgiver : https://text.egwwritings.org/publication.php?pubtype=Periodical&bookCode=ST&lang=en&collection=2&section=all&year=1910&month=March&day=22&paragraphnumber=2&QUERY=%22the+name+and+the+title+of+the+Lawgiver%22&resultId=1

Comment: Final comment - the articles I mention are not designed to prove that YHWH cannot be a title. They are designed to show that YHWH is seen as the Divine Name. As for Ellen G. White, one claim or suggestion a fact does not make.

Comment: @Lesley  Thank you for all your comments!!  Ellen G. White understood that either YHWH is a title or YHWH your Elohim is a title.